# Finiding the number of times li is cliked

Tags: javascript, html-lists, double-click

I have this html code wherein I have many li elements.
On doubleclicking each li element, a window like div appears. as many number of windows appear for that specific window as the number of times i click on that window.
My problem is, how to prevent opening more than one window for a particular li element?

Can i have some method or function in javascript using which I can count the number of times I have clicked on a particular li element?

Comment: Why don't you test for the existence of the `window like div` before opening another? What have you tried?

Comment: You can add a class to the `li` after it's been clicked, and then check for that class in your code...

Comment: You can implement `Singleton` concept for your `window`. And everytime when `li` will be clicked , just update the content of that `window` according to clicked `li`  and then show it.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can tie the event listener with the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method, which assures that the callback only ever runs once per element.

Comment: If you want more help, you'll have to provide some code...

Answer (score 2):

create an object with the window/div ID as key and set it on true if opened and on false if the "window" is closed.

so you just have to show the window only if the value is false

```
openedWindows.li1 = false;
openedWindows.li2 = false;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For easy interaction with the DOM, I recommend the library [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

If you decide to use jQuery just use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var liClicked = [];
    $("li").dblclick(function() {
        if (liClicked.indexOf($(this).index()) != -1) return;
        liClicked.push($(this).index());
        alert("new click");
    });
});
```

Comment: Where it was mentioned ,that the OP uses jQuery?

Comment: Whoops. I guess I just kind of assumed... I  edited the answer to recommend jQuery before showing the code. This would be fairly difficult without jQuery.

Comment: would the indexes persist if new `li`s were added dynamically?

Comment: No... I figure he's probably not dynamically adding list elements, though. If he only appended the `li` element and changed the event so it's live, it would work, though.

Answer (score -3):

Do you bind that function onto the li elements? Just unbind on specific element to prevent further popping..or remove onclick attribute contents, depending on code....

eg:

```
function openWindow(obj){
//your code - fired by onclick passing 'this'

obj.onclick = null;

}
```

Comment: The OP seems to be asking how to make sure that multiple clicks on the same element don't open multiple windows, not to limit the number of times that the window for a particular element ever opens is once.

Comment: @natlee75 - not really : "how to prevent opening more than one window for a particular li element?" - to me this sounds as one per li element